# How to scroll down upto page end where dynamic contents are loading in vba chrome selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using VBA chrome selenium for data extraction. My code is working fine for static contents but I am unable to scroll down to page end. My sample url is following "https://www.zhihu.com/question/533841804"

Till now I developed following code to scroll down.

```
Do While EndofPage = False
PrevPageHeight = CurrentPageHeight
CurrentPageHeight = driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var CurrentPageHeight=document.body.scrollHeight;return CurrentPageHeight;")
Sleep 3000
If PrevPageHeight = CurrentPageHeight Then
EndofPage = True
End If
Loop
```

Comment: anyone have some idea regarding above scrolling issue